# How to completely remove Visual Studio from mac?

Tags: macos, uninstall, visual-studio

I recently installed Visual Studio for mac right after the day it was launched. It consumed 20 gb of my disc space, so I decided to remove it. I went in to the applications folder and moved recently installed components associated with the installation to the trash. But it did not free any space at all. So I searched online and followed the following link for uninstallation: [Uninstalling Xamarin](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/installation/uninstalling_xamarin/)

After following the link and entering all the terminal commands, I was only able to free up 10 gb of storage. How do I free up the rest 10 gb of the storage ?

Answer (score 25):

In case anyone else having the same question visited here, please visit the [official guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/uninstall).

The following is quoted from the original guide which was updated at 2017-4-14.

> #### Uninstall Visual Studio for Mac App
>
> > Step 1. Locate Visual Studio.app in the /Applications directory and drag it to the Trash Can. Alternatively, right-click and select Move
> >     to Trash.
> >
> > Step 2. Remove all traces of Visual Studio for Mac
>
> Execute the following commands in your terminal:
>
> ```
> sudo rm -rf "/Applications/Visual Studio.app"
> rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/VisualStudio
> rm -rf ~/Library/Preferences/VisualStudio
> rm -rf "~/Library/Preferences/Visual Studio"
> rm -rf ~/Library/Logs/VisualStudio
> rm -rf ~/Library/VisualLodStudio
> ```
>
> #### Uninstall Xamarin.Android
>
> ```
> sudo rm -rf /Developer/MonoDroid
> rm -rf ~/Library/MonoAndroid
> sudo pkgutil --forget com.xamarin.android.pkg
> sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Android.framework
> ```
>
> #### Uninstall Xamarin.iOS
>
> ```
> rm -rf ~/Library/MonoTouch
> sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework
> sudo rm -rf /Developer/MonoTouch
> sudo pkgutil --forget com.xamarin.monotouch.pkg
> sudo pkgutil --forget com.xamarin.xamarin-ios-build-host.pkg
> ```
>
> #### Uninstall Xamarin.Mac
>
> ```
> sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework
> rm -rf ~/Library/Xamarin.Mac
> ```
>
> #### Uninstall Workbooks and Inspector
>
> ```
> sudo /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Interactive.framework/Versions/Current/uninstall
> ```
>
> #### Uninstall the Visual Studio Installer
>
> ```
> rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/XamarinInstaller/
> rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/VisualStudioInstaller/
> rm -rf ~/Library/Logs/XamarinInstaller/
> rm -rf ~/Library/Logs/VisualStudioInstaller/
> rm -rf ~/Library/Preferences/Xamarin/
> rm -rf "~/Library/Preferences/Visual Studio/"
> ```
>
> #### Uninstall Mono SDK (MDK)
>
> > **Warning**
> >
> > **There are other applications outside of Xamarin which also use Mono, such as Unity. Be sure that there are no other dependencies on
> >     Mono before uninstalling it.**
>
> ```
> sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework
> sudo pkgutil --forget com.xamarin.mono-MDK.pkg
> ```

---

#### Other apps with name prefix *Xamarin*

The official guide didn't mention it, but I found there were other apps named *Xamarin.xxxx* in my library directory. I simply moved them to trash.

Comment: @DavidPostill♦ @Pierre.Vriens Added quotes.

Comment: Much better. You need to block quote everything though. Please read [How to reference material written by others](https://superuser.com/help/referencing). You must block quote text that has been written by some else. See [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help). I've fixed it for you this time, but please pay attention to this in future.

Comment: Thanks for this!  I also had `~/Library/Developer/Xamarin/` taking up 10+ GB.

Answer (score 12):

May be this would be better solution (no need to follow each step): https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/master/mac/resources/uninstall-vsmac.sh :

```
#!/bin/sh

# Uninstall Visual Studio for Mac
echo "Uninstalling Visual Studio for Mac..."

sudo rm -rf "/Applications/Visual Studio.app"
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/VisualStudio
rm -rf ~/Library/Preferences/VisualStudio
rm -rf "~/Library/Preferences/Visual Studio"
rm -rf ~/Library/Logs/VisualStudio
rm -rf ~/Library/VisualStudio
rm -rf ~/Library/Preferences/Xamarin/
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xamarin

# Uninstall Xamarin.Android
echo "Uninstalling Xamarin.Android..."

sudo rm -rf /Developer/MonoDroid
rm -rf ~/Library/MonoAndroid
sudo pkgutil --forget com.xamarin.android.pkg
sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Android.framework


# Uninstall Xamarin.iOS
echo "Uninstalling Xamarin.iOS..."

rm -rf ~/Library/MonoTouch
sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework
sudo rm -rf /Developer/MonoTouch
sudo pkgutil --forget com.xamarin.monotouch.pkg
sudo pkgutil --forget com.xamarin.xamarin-ios-build-host.pkg


# Uninstall Xamarin.Mac
echo "Uninstalling Xamarin.Mac..."

sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework
rm -rf ~/Library/Xamarin.Mac


# Uninstall Workbooks and Inspector
echo "Uninstalling Workbooks and Inspector..."

sudo /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Interactive.framework/Versions/Current/uninstall


# Uninstall the Visual Studio for Mac Installer
echo "Uninstalling the Visual Studio for Mac Installer..."

rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/XamarinInstaller/
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/VisualStudioInstaller/
rm -rf ~/Library/Logs/XamarinInstaller/
rm -rf ~/Library/Logs/VisualStudioInstaller/

# Uninstall the Xamarin Profiler
echo "Uninstalling the Xamarin Profiler..."

sudo rm -rf "/Applications/Xamarin Profiler.app"

echo "Finished Uninstallation process."
```

If you haven't dealt with bash script before, you may look at its documentation too: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/uninstall

Actually, it is pretty easy. Create a file with extension .sh (for example, vsremover.sh) and paste the code above. Save. Open *terminal* application, go to the place where you saved the file (for example: `cd /Users/yourname/Desktop`) and type the following:

```
chmod +x vsremover.sh
```

Then run it:

```
./vsremover.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using MacOS X Catalina, after I followed the link @lowatt provided: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/uninstall?view=vsmac-2019#uninstall-android-sdk-and-java-sdk

I also noticed that `echo $PATH` containing some useless environment variables:
`/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/Applications/Xamarin Workbooks.app/Contents/SharedSupport/path-bin`.

To remove these, go to folder `/etc/paths.d/`("cmd+shift+." to toggle display of hidden files/folders) and find: `dotnet`, `dotnet-cli-...`. Double click each one, i.e. If you double click `dotnet` you will find a path `/usr/local/share/dotnet`, go to that folder and delete it. After you're done, delete these `dotnet`, `dotnet-cli-...` too. (You should make sure by your own that the other programs do not use **dotnet**).